# Usar variável de C++ em assembly (Arduino)

Tags: c++, ponteiro, arduino, assembly

Eu echei um código interessante nesta [página](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/sort-of-running-an-arduino-program-from-memory/).

```
const uint8_t MachineCode[44] PROGMEM = {
0x25, 0x9A, 0x2D, 0x9A, 0x40, 0xE5, 0x5F, 0xEF,
0x6F, 0xEF, 0x6A, 0x95, 0xF1, 0xF7, 0x5A, 0x95,
0xE1, 0xF7, 0x4A, 0x95, 0xD1, 0xF7, 0x2D, 0x98,
0x40, 0xE5, 0x5F, 0xEF, 0x6F, 0xEF, 0x6A, 0x95,
0xF1, 0xF7, 0x5A, 0x95, 0xE1, 0xF7, 0x4A, 0x95,
0xD1, 0xF7, 0xEB, 0xCF
};

const uint8_t *ptr = MachineCode;

void setup() {
  //get address of code and call it
  //Creio que o ERRO esteja aqui:
  asm(
    "lds r30, ptr   \n\t"
    "lds r31, ptr+1 \n\t"
    "lsr r30        \n\t"
    "icall          \n\t"
  );
}

void loop() {
  //never reach here
}
```

Fui executar o código no meu Arduino, mas recebi este erro:

> `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Arduino\xxx/xxx.ino:19: undefined reference to 'ptr'`

Creio que seja porque o código assembly não está conseguindo acessar a variável `ptr`. Sou iniciante em C\C++.

Comment: Lembre se, que trabalhar com microcontroladores podem requerer libraries, ou no caso do PIC por exemplo, um compilador, como C18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nada de errado com o seu código.

É sempre uma boa prática incluir o *header* `Arduino.h` em seu código:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
```